# VHDL: enumeration type minimal dimension

Tags: vhdl

this is my code:

> type      T_mean_state  is (IDLE_S, WRITE_NEW_S, READ_OLD_S_W,
>   READ_OLD_S);

The enumeration type is encoded by synthesis tool with no minimal dimension hardware resources. 
Have I to specify minimal HW dimensions before proceeding with the synthesis?

Thanks all.

Comment: What synthesizer are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand your question but here is an example of how I'll enumerate the states that I have  :

```
   type STATE_TYPE is (IDLE, GNT1, GNT2, GNT3, GNT4, GNT5, GNT6, GNT7, GNT8); 
    attribute ENUM_ENCODING: string; 
    attribute ENUM_ENCODING of STATE_TYPE: type is 
    "0000 0001 0010 0100 1000 0011 0101 0110 1001"; 
    signal STATE, NEXT_STATE: STATE_TYPE;
```

Comment: @tosone if it did help you ? you may accept  as an answer so other users  don't spend their time trying to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Different synthesis tools may encode the states differently; or you can control the encoding style in a "process properties" menu or command line options. In any case, the synthesis report will describe the specific encoding chosen by synthesis to best suit your targets - speed or size for example.

So look at the synth report; most synth tools are quite good at optimisation, so it may already have chosen the encoding you want. Or you can find out how to set the options for your tool.

And as "engine" says, you can explicitly specify the states if you need to; though that is usually not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Leave it to the synthesiser to figure out how best to represent your enumerated type, unless you have specific reasons to want a particular representation.

For example, you might want to use a gray-coded representation in some critical state-machine.  Control at this level happens outside the language proper, either through attributes applied to signals or using a constraints file.  You'll have to read the documentation for the tools you are using to find out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

May have something to do with it.

BR

> Note: If an Enumeration Type represents the states of a state
>   machine, using the enum_encoding attribute to specify a manual state
>   encoding prevents the Compiler from recognizing state machines based
>   on the Enumeration Type. Instead, the Compiler processes these state
>   machines as "regular" logic using the encoding specified by the
>   attribute, and they are not listed as state machines in the Report
>   window for the project. If you wish to control the encoding for a
>   recognized state machine, use the State Machine Processing logic
>   option or the syn_encoding attribute. For more information on properly
>   implementing state machines in VHDL, refer to Implementing State
>   Machines.

http://quartushelp.altera.com/15.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_file_dir_enum_encoding.htm